# Python error: ImportError: No module named src.core.setcore?

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm new here and I have found no solution to my problem yet. I am currently learning to program in C but I don't know much about python, and what happens is that when I try to run a script it gives me this error:

```
 root@ubuntu:/usr/share/set/src/core# ./fasttrack.py 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "./fasttrack.py", line 2, in <module>
from src.core.setcore import *
ImportError: No module named src.core.setcore
```

Can someone tell what's happening here so I can fix this problem? (I'm using ubuntu terminal just in case.) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems like you don't have the module `src.core.setcore` but the script trying to use it.

Comment: So you're learning C, but using Python... Interesting combination. Have you bothered trying to read the traceback? Either there is no module, or the system can't find it.

Comment: Well, I am learning C but now I need to use this python script, it wasn't written by me anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the script from a directory two levels up the tree.

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/set# ./fasttrack.py
```

The import statements encountered in python search for modules relative to the current directory and the directories in the Python path.

Comment: The terminal says the script was not found, I'll keep searching for an answer.

Comment: Well yes of course since it resided in `/user/share/set/src/core`. Copy it over to the current directory: `cp ./src/core/fasttrack.py .` and then try to execute the above command again.